# Six undefined words

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

- *X is an important part of something. That 'something' is a constituent of Y and depends on Z.*
- *A, B and C are important parts of another something. This 'something' is also a constituent of Y and depends on X and Z.*

---

***Identify X, Y, Z and A, B, C with the help of the following three operations.***

---

**Operation 1 (Examples)**

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| Crime | Prime |
| Toast | Boast |
| A | X |

---

**Operation 2 (Examples)**

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| Smile | Miles |
| Phase | Shape |
| B | Y |

---

**Operation 3 (Examples)**

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| Flick | Lick |
| Bring | Ring |
| C | Z |

---

Comment: Is the 'something' referred to in the two bullet points the *same* 'something', or two *different* 'somethings'?

Comment: @Stiv Different 'somethings'. I'll modify the post to make it clear.

Comment: Would [Mouth -> Youth] fit operation 1?

Comment: @Chengarda Yes. It would.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the best I have so far:

> A = Hand B = Heart  C = Brain
>  
>  X = Land Y = Earth Z = Rain
>  
>  Land is an important part of Earth's surface. The surface is a
>  constituent of Earth and depends on Rain. Hand, Heart and Brain are
>  important parts of a Human. The Human is also a constituent of Earth
>  and depends on Rain and Land.

It's possible I have it partially correct, or maybe not correct at all.

Comment: Amazing job to have cracked this! For the sake of satisfaction, can you change A and X to five letter singular words? Your answer is valid as it is now but I had five letters in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Given the previous answer and request to change "A and X to five letter singular words", I'll go with

> A = liver, X = river

(I'd rather have made a comment - but just startet here without reputation.. ;) )

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for! Nice..